# Cannot access the nested loop element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access the element in my nested loop.
I've accessing the loop element of the first loop just fine using $(this), however the secnod element cannot be accessed using $(this).
How do I access the second element?

```
$('.buttons').each(function(){
    width = 100 / $(this).length;
    $(this).each(function () {
        $(this).width = width + '%';
    });
});
```

The above code sets the first loop element of the first loop and not the inner one.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting $(this) to refer to in the inner loop?

Comment: could you post the markup please?

Comment: $(this) is representing only single object, thus each loop on that is meaningless.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan
Well how can I access the each element in the inner loop then?

Also the inner loop is a bunch of div elements

Comment: what's the second loop for?

Comment: @koala_dev
The second loop is for accessing the individual child divs of the buttons div.

Comment: The outer "each" loops over all the elements with class "button."  What do you think the inner "each" is looping over?

Comment: What you expect to get on the $(this).each? Put ur html code

Comment: @JordanAxe, in your code you are iterating $(this) object. Where is the bunch of divs?

Comment: Kundan is right, the inner loop won't have any elements. If you want to access the children of each button, you'll need to replace the inner loop with $(this).children().each(...)

Comment: You probably want $(this).children().

Comment: Actually, I think the inner loop should fire and your 'this' will be the button. Assigning width that way won't work. You want to use $(this).css('width', width+'%');

Answer (score 3):

based on your comments, you're trying to access child divs inside each class with button on it.

```
$('.buttons').each(function(){
    var children = $(this).find('div'), width = 100 / children.length;
    children.each(function () {
        $(this).width(width + '%');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).width` returns a number. You can't "set" a number

Comment: It's not the way I would have done it, I would have used jQuery's `width()` method to set it. I just didn't change his since a quick lookup seems like it still would work: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp

Comment: Sorry, I said that wrong. `$(this)` is a jQuery object. `.width` is a reference to the jQuery `.width()` method. You can't "set" a function. You can't interchange DOM properties and jQuery methods. If you wanted to set the DOM property, which I wouldn't suggest, as the link you post shows, you would use `$(this)[0].style.width` anyways, but is unnecessary

Comment: yea, you're right, I just tried it out in jsfiddle. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. I edited one minor thing in your first example too

Comment: I would remove the first code sample from your answer as it only sets the width of all `.buttons` to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

I believe this is what your looking for, it will set the width of each button evenly so they add up to 100%;

```
$('.buttons').each(function(){
    var $buttons = $(this).find('.button');
    var width = 100 / $buttons.length;
    $buttons.width(width+'%');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4dTc/)**

Answer (score 0):

"this" is the interator in the context of the each loop, always. So to reference the interator of an outerloop you must assign its reference to a variable.

```
$('.buttons').each(function(){
    var jqOuterThis = $(this);
    var outerWidth = 100 / $(this).length;
    $(jqOuterThis).each(function () {
        $(jqOuterThis).width(outerWidth + '%');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to utilize the arguments "each" has.

```
$('.buttons').each(function(i, element) { ... });
```

This way you can use $(element) in any further nesting (unless overwritten by identical argument name by the later use of each).

"i" is the iterator variable. If it's on the 3rd found element i will be 2, 4th it will be 3, etc.